# How to remove a character in vi

Tags: vi

Inside a file, I have many occurrences of a specific character (^ in this case).

For example:

```
"bower": "^1.8.2",
"dexie": "^1.5.1",
"elixir-typescript": "^2.1.0",
```

I want to remove all ^ character. How to proceed?

By the instruction, I should do something like:

```
:%s/^/
or 
:%s/^/SOMETHIHNG/g
```

Without success. Any tip?

Comment: ```:%s/\^//g```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is a special character that matches the beginning of a line so it must be escaped with backslash. Try `:%s/\^/something/g`

Answer (score 1):

When escaping special characters you could use another placeholder to "prettify" and avoid to many slashes, for example:

```
:%s#\^##g
```